# Set an Image as a Node to create a Path Transition JAVA/JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx

```
package application;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
//from www  . j a va 2 s  .  c  o  m
public class Experiment3 extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final Group group = new Group();
    final Scene scene = new Scene(group, 600, 400, Color.GHOSTWHITE);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("JavaFX 2 Animations");
    stage.show();
    final Circle circle = new Circle(20, 20, 15);
    circle.setFill(Color.DARKRED);
    final Image i1 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("IMG_Strength/Abs1.png"),400,400,false,false);

    final Path path = new Path();
    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(20, 20));
    path.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(30, 10, 380, 120, 200, 120));
    path.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(200, 1120, 110, 240, 380, 240));
    path.setOpacity(0.5);

    group.getChildren().add(path);
    group.getChildren().add(i1);
    final PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();

    pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(8.0));
    pathTransition.setDelay(Duration.seconds(.5));
    pathTransition.setPath(path);
    pathTransition.setNode(circle);
    pathTransition
        .setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
    pathTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    pathTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
    pathTransition.play();
  }

  public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
    Application.launch(arguments);
  }
```

}

It returns an error at final Image because it is not a Node. So my qu is how can I make the image a node in order to add it to group.getChildren.add(i1)
My purpose is to make the image moving in a rectangular path

Comment: well, the error tells you the reason, doesn't it ;) To solve, scan the api to learn which node can hold an Image .. And please take the time to type complete English words (question vs. qu)

Comment: @kleopatra Oh yes, I found it. Thank you.